# how to use different linters in different projects in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimelinter

I have startet using a different linter (standard) in a new project. Also: No semicolons, indentation by 2 spaces and more.

Other projects still use jshint. And a different style: with semicolons, indentation by 4 spaces and more.

When I open an old project the code is riddled with error messages as the different indentation and semicolons occur on every line...

I know how to set linter settings per project. But (how) can I activate / deactivate linters per project?

Comment: This is an old one, but did you mange to make it work? I'm facing the same question here.

Comment: Yes and no: I changed to Atom where this seems not to be an issue

Comment: I see :D, well thanks a lot for replying to this old thread!